# How do I save the filter for tables in SQLdeveloper?

Tags: sql, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

How do I save the filter for tables in SQLdeveloper?
They keep reseting after after closing the programm.

> Filter
>
> This dialog box is displayed when you
>   right-click a connection node or an
>   object type node (such as Tables) in
>   the Connections navigator and select
>   Apply Filter. Use this box to limit
>   the number of objects of that type
>   that are displayed, according to one
>   or more filter criteria that you
>   specify.

Comment: Don't know - but the filter feature is more of an ad-hoc thing, I think. If you find you run a particular query often, it's probably a good idea to save it in a .SQL script and just run it whenever you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to save the filters, but if you browse to the tables on which the filters were applied, there is autocomplete feature which will type in previously entered values

Answer (score 1):

I don't know since which version of SQLDeveloper there is such option but I have 4.1 and after restarting it - filters for tables in that context are kept. So - if someone still has such problem - needs upgrade SQLDeveloper